# An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, dto

I'm working on the `Spring boot JPA Gridle project`. Current `Swagger` is running, and an error occurs while `DTO` is in progress. Modules seem to be colliding with each other.

An error occurs when I install a `swagger` module, proceed with the swagger, and install the module for DTO. The following modules produce an error:

`compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'`

And the error is as follows.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-17 01:26:38.657 ERROR 4688 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsManager.createContextBuilder(DocumentationPluginsManager.java:152)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/****/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/95fc8c13037630f4aba9c51141f535becec00fe6/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/****/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/2.0.0.RELEASE/95fc8c13037630f4aba9c51141f535becec00fe6/spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The things I tried through the search are as well.

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.plugin', name: 'spring-plugin-core', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-data-rest', version: '2.9.2'
```

Neither of them helped me.

Does anyone have the same problem as me?

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a conflict between Swagger and Hateoas modules. A number of search results have found a solution.

The solution was to add a new module and register `Bean` for it.

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.plugin', name: 'spring-plugin-core', version: '1.2.0.RELEASE'
```

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```java
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public LinkDiscoverers discoverers() {
        List<LinkDiscoverer> plugins = new ArrayList<>();
        plugins.add(new CollectionJsonLinkDiscoverer());
        return new LinkDiscoverers(SimplePluginRegistry.create(plugins));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was a conflict between JPA and Hateoas dependencies.

The solution for me was to remove the JPA dependency since I was interested in using the Hateoas module instead.

Changed this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

To this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me was a conflict between the Swagger and the JPA, so I had to upgrade the SpringBoot from 2.1.9-RELEASE to 2.7.5.